# Tourist visa to Hong Kong - financial proof for high school grad and am I eligible?

Tags: visas, paperwork, proof-provenance-of-funds, hong-kong, solo-travel

What kind of documentation can I provide for a Hong Kong tourist visa regarding proof of sufficient funds as a legal adult/18 but is a (soon) high school graduate? The purpose of travel is a leisure trip with friends - a “grad trip”.

There will be no proof of labour contract. Does a sponsorship letter from an individual qualify? Along with documentation of *their* bank balance and financial standing, but not my own, considering I’m still in school. The individual does not live in HK and is not going on the trip. I guess I am asking about the issue “adults not being able to sponsor other adults” if that’s the rule for visas.

Please help advise on what would be best to do in this situation. Or help confirm that there would be zero success at a visa? Thank you so much

Comment: Which country do you live in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for you, "just finished school" is a typical situation for young people to leave home to seek their fortune abroad -- especially if home is a country with low socioeconomic development. The main task of visa officers is to keep those people *out* -- so in order to get a visa you'll need to present a convincing reason why seeking your fortune in Hong Kong *can't* be your plan.

Of course you'll need to show that you can *afford* a pleasure trip to HK, and you would need your sponsor's information for that. But in the big picture that's a relatively minor hurdle.

You'll need to show that you have a promising future *to return to* in Cambodia. If you don't have a job lined up, being accepted for a university or other further studies outside HK may do, if you can also explain how you'll pay for that education -- i.e. your living costs *and* if applicable tution fees or the like.

But if you don't have that, you chance of qualifying for a visa is -- by design! -- very slim.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I’m sorry to ask, what does evidence of a job lined up look like? Supposing conditional letters to colleges overseas, not yet accepted, is not eligible. Anyone else that is able to help, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: @antsinthegrass: Around here I would expect a contract of employment, with a specified start date, signed by both parties. But it would depend a lot on local practices which kind of documentation is expected to exist.

Comment: @antsinthegrass I suppose if you have official, conditional offers to a known university abroad (i.e., not Random Community College or London South Bank University), and proof that you have enough financial support to actually go, would actually be convincing evidence that you won't overstay. After all, if you have a promising future in your studies, it's very unlikely that you'll overstay to illegally work in HK.